# Javascript: When does a global get created

Tags: javascript

At what point would the global variable be created in the following function below; before test() is executed or after?

```
var test = function(){
  foo = 5
}

test()
```

Edit: I am referring to foo variable

Comment: It would be helpful if you could clarify whether you're curious about `test` or `foo`.

Comment: @Pointy, I think he asks about `foo`, since it's created without `var` and is designed to be global

Comment: It would still be good to actually say.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ..before `test()` is executed or after?

It depends which global variable you're referring to, `test` or `foo`.

For `test`: Before. `var` declarations are "hoisted," they're processed before any step-by-step code in the scope where they appear is executed; global ones are executed prior to any step-by-step code at global scope in that script. (Subsequent scripts are handled separately, first vars, then step-by-step code.)

For `foo`: During.

The order of that code is:

1. Declarations occur:

   1. The global `test` is created with the value `undefined`.
2. Step-by-step execution is done:

   1. The assignment `test = function() { foo = 5 }` is executed

      1. The function is created
      2. It's assigned to `test`
   2. `test()` is executed

      1. The assignment `foo = 5` is done, creating an *implicit global* called `foo` (more on my blog: [*The Horror of Implicit Globals*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/horror-of-implicit-globals.html))

Answer (score 2):

The variable `foo` will be create when an interpreter will try to assign the variable `foo`, so during the function execution.

```
var test = function(){
  foo = 5
}

window.hasOwnProperty('foo'); // false

test()

window.hasOwnProperty('foo'); // true
```

Answer (score 2):

This is easy enough to test:

```js
// The code within the function won't be evaluated (nor any variables within it be hoisted)
// until that code is invoked
var test = function(){
  foo = 5;
}

// This will fail saying that foo is undefined, so we know that the global 
// hasn't been created yet
//console.log(foo);

// Call the function and force the code within it to be evaluated
test()

// Works. The global has been created..
console.log(foo);
```

Comment: You can safely use `console.log(typeof foo)` to see whether it's been created (will be `"undefined"` before and `"number"` after). Also `this.hasOwnProperty("foo")` (or `window.hasOwnProperty("foo")`).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Yes, but I showed it this way for two reasons. 1) getting the error is pretty convincing evidence for the variable not being created and 2) it's the simplest test to perform.

Comment: *"getting the error is pretty convincing evidence for the variable not being created"* :-D True!

Answer (score 0):

Here in your code

```
 var test = function(){  foo = 5};   
     test();
```

**test** is the global variable which holds the Function object. It is created before test() function invocation during global execution environment .

**foo** is also global  variable as no var, let or const keyword is there. But it will be created after invocation of test() function.

Comment: `foo` is not a local variable - it's global and will persist after `test()` returns. See my code snippet below for an example.

Comment: @scott u are right , I overlooked that there is no var, let or const keyword

Comment: @RafiqueAhmed Pretty huge thing you "overlooked" - that was the question...

Comment: While you've corrected your local vs. global error. You still haven't actually answered the OPs question.